# Find text section and insert into table

Tags: vba, ms-word

everyone.

I've only been immersed in the world of macros for a few days now and don't really know my way around.
I have several Word 2016 documents that I want to reformat. Each document has exactly the same structure (see attached file).

**What I have done so far** (and how it works)
Since the images are distorted and too large, I first set them in the same aspect ratio and reduce them to 50%.

```
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .ScaleHeight = 50
            .ScaleWidth = 50
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

Then I search for the text lines "Slide notes" and replace them with the text "Speaker text:".
And also the text "Text Captions" I replace in the same way, with "Screen text:"

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="Slide notes", _
ReplaceWith:="Speaker text:", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="Text Captions", _
ReplaceWith:="Screen text:", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

**And now I just can't get any further**
Next, on each page, the text between "Speaker text" and "Screen text" should be filled into a table with two columns.

- Ideally, the two columns should have a division of 2/3 to 1/3 (at full width).
- At each line break, a new table line should be inserted
- The table should end with the last entry (before "Screen text:")

**This is the script, how I try to create the two-column table** but unfortunately not working correctly.

```
Dim rng As Range
sTx = "Speaker text:"
With ActiveDocument
Set rng = .Range(.Characters(InStr(.Content, sTx) + Len(sTx) + 1).Start, .Characters(InStr(.Content, "Screen text:") - 1).End)
rng.Select
rng.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs, NumColumns:=1, _
NumRows:=2, InitialColumnWidth:=CentimetersToPoints(5), AutoFitBehavior _
:=wdAutoFitFixed
With rng.Tables(1)
.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
.ApplyStyleLastRow = False
.ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
.ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
'Apply borders around table
.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With
.Tables(1).Range.Columns.Add ' InsertColumnsRight
.Tables(1).Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=184.05, RulerStyle:= _
wdAdjustFirstColumn
.Tables(1).Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=99.2, RulerStyle:= _
wdAdjustFirstColumn
End With
```

**Unfortunately, it doesn't work the way I want it to.**

- Only one table is created (on the first page)
- Only one frame is visible (no subdivision)
- There is always an empty row (table)
- The table does not have the full widthe

Before / After

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
    With .InlineShapes(i)
      .ScaleHeight = 50
      .ScaleWidth = 50
    End With
  Next i
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Slide notes*Text Captions"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Paragraphs.First.Range.Text = "Speaker text:"
    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = "Screen text:" & vbCr
    .Start = .Paragraphs.First.Range.End
    .End = .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start
    Do While .Characters.First.Text = vbCr
      .Characters.First.Delete
    Loop
    With .Duplicate
      .Find.Execute FindText:="^13^13", ReplaceWith:="^t^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      .ConvertToTable Separator:=vbTab, NumRows:=.Paragraphs.Count, NumColumns:=2, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
      With .Tables(1)
        .AllowAutoFit = False
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
        .Borders.Enable = True
        .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
        .Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=.PreferredWidth * 2 / 3, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustProportional
        Do While .Range.Characters.Last.Next = vbCr
          .Range.Characters.Last.Next.Delete
        Loop
      End With
    End With
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot macropod - It works!
You are fantastic

Answer (score 0):

@macropod
May I ask you to explain your script to me.
The first part (the proportional reduction of the images) is clear so far.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
    With .InlineShapes(i)
      .ScaleHeight = 50
      .ScaleWidth = 50
    End With
```

With the second section (replacing the two phrases), I already have more problems.

```
  Next i
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Slide notes*Text Captions"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Paragraphs.First.Range.Text = "Speaker text:"
    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = "Screen text:" & vbCr
    .Start = .Paragraphs.First.Range.End
    .End = .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start
    Do While .Characters.First.Text = vbCr
      .Characters.First.Delete
    Loop
```

And I am hopelessly overwhelmed with the last part.

```
    With .Duplicate
      .Find.Execute FindText:="^13^13", ReplaceWith:="^t^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      .ConvertToTable Separator:=vbTab, NumRows:=.Paragraphs.Count, NumColumns:=2, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
      With .Tables(1)
        .AllowAutoFit = False
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
        .Borders.Enable = True
        .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
        .Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=.PreferredWidth * 2 / 3, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustProportional
        Do While .Range.Characters.Last.Next = vbCr
          .Range.Characters.Last.Next.Delete
        Loop
      End With
    End With
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Please excuse me for inquiring. But I would like to understand the script.
Because I would also like to rewrite the script so that I can use it without the "Screen text:" section.
Thank you very much and best regards.

Comment: The code uses a *wildcard* Find to locate everything from 'Slide notes' to 'Text Captions'. It then loops through all matches, replacing those two phrases as per your specs, then converting the intervening content to a two-column table, again as per your specs. There is also some clean-up along the way (both before & after the table is created), deleting superfluous paragraph breaks and, within the area that's to become the table, converting the repeated paragraph breaks to tab-paragraph break sequences so the tabs can be used to designate where the column separators should go.

Comment: Thank you very much macropod!